# Spidermonkey pointing to a NSPR/DIST directory

Tags: cross-compiling, spidermonkey, nspr

I've been trying to cross-compile Spidermonkey and I am stuck with the problem wherein `prtypes.h` (NSPR) is unrecognizable. I alread tried modifying `Makefile.ref`/`config.mk`/`jsconfig.mk` to point to a desired NSPR/DIS directory. I must have missed some basic steps because it still won't make things work.
Do you have any ideas on how to properly modify the makefiles to point my spidermonkey to the right NSPR libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already solved your problem, but still...

`make JS_DIST=dir JS_THREADSAFE=1 -f Makefile.ref`

`dir` is where nspr is installed, I think it must be **full path** to its directory (like /usr/local/nspr or /home//mozilla/nsprpub/dist if it's not installed), otherwise it has some issues that might make you want to modify spidermonkey's makeifle.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference/JS_THREADSAFE